# Heroku open doesn't work. "ValueError: The file 'css/style.css' could not be found"

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am having trouble with heroku deployment. When I open the app in the browser, it's throwing me an error message that says:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an unexpected internal
>   server error (generated by waitress)

How can I fix this? Below is the heroku logs error message. As you can see at the end, it's showing me that heroku couldn't find the css.file. Never experinenced this issue in local environment.

Thank you for your time.

```
(venv) Ryujis-MacBook-Pro:ryujihellowebapp ryujimorita$ heroku logs
2016-10-25T18:40:40.739865+00:00 app[web.1]:     hashed_name = self.stored_name(clean_name)
2016-10-25T18:40:40.739866+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 280, in stored_name
2016-10-25T18:40:40.739868+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 94, in hashed_name
2016-10-25T18:40:40.739868+00:00 app[web.1]:     (clean_name, self))
2016-10-25T18:40:40.739867+00:00 app[web.1]:     cache_name = self.clean_name(self.hashed_name(name))
2016-10-25T18:40:40.739870+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: The file 'css/style.css' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7ff8f01577d0>.
2016-10-25T18:49:16.277858+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=ryujihellowebapp.herokuapp.com request_id=b7fa0f0e-33f5-4a20-a13d-272441b50c37 fwd="173.55.124.51" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=91ms status=500 bytes=269
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280970+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280980+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280982+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280986+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280987+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280989+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280989+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/collection/views.py", line 18, in index
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280991+00:00 app[web.1]:     'things': things,
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280992+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 67, in render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280993+00:00 app[web.1]:     template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280994+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 97, in render_to_string
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280995+00:00 app[web.1]:     return template.render(context, request)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280995+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 95, in render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280996+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.template.render(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280997+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 206, in render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280998+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._render(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280999+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 197, in _render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.280999+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.nodelist.render(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281000+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 992, in render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281002+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.render(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281003+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 173, in render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281004+00:00 app[web.1]:     return compiled_parent._render(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281001+00:00 app[web.1]:     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281002+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281004+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 197, in _render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281005+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.nodelist.render(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281006+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 992, in render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281007+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281006+00:00 app[web.1]:     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281008+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.render(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281008+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 103, in render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281009+00:00 app[web.1]:     url = self.url(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281010+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py", line 16, in url
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281011+00:00 app[web.1]:     return static(path)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281012+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py", line 9, in static
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281013+00:00 app[web.1]:     return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281014+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 131, in url
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281014+00:00 app[web.1]:     hashed_name = self.stored_name(clean_name)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281016+00:00 app[web.1]:     cache_name = self.clean_name(self.hashed_name(name))
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281016+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 94, in hashed_name
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281015+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 280, in stored_name
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281017+00:00 app[web.1]:     (clean_name, self))
2016-10-25T18:49:16.281019+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: The file 'css/style.css' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7ff8f01577d0>.
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283158+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:waitress:Exception when serving /
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283160+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283161+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/channel.py", line 338, in service
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283162+00:00 app[web.1]:     task.service()
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283165+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/task.py", line 169, in service
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283165+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.execute()
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283166+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/task.py", line 399, in execute
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283167+00:00 app[web.1]:     app_iter = self.channel.server.application(env, start_response)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283168+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 66, in __call__
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283168+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.application(environ, start_response)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283169+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 177, in __call__
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283170+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.get_response(request)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283171+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 230, in get_response
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283172+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 296, in handle_uncaught_exception
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283171+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283173+00:00 app[web.1]:     return callback(request, **param_dict)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283173+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283174+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283174+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 63, in server_error
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283175+00:00 app[web.1]:     return http.HttpResponseServerError(template.render())
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283176+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 95, in render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283176+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.template.render(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283177+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 206, in render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283178+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._render(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283179+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 197, in _render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283180+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 992, in render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283181+00:00 app[web.1]:     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283181+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283179+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.nodelist.render(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283182+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.render(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283183+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 173, in render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283184+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 197, in _render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283185+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.nodelist.render(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283185+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 992, in render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283186+00:00 app[web.1]:     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283183+00:00 app[web.1]:     return compiled_parent._render(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283187+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.render(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283188+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 103, in render
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283189+00:00 app[web.1]:     url = self.url(context)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283190+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py", line 16, in url
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283190+00:00 app[web.1]:     return static(path)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283191+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py", line 9, in static
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283192+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 131, in url
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283187+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283194+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 280, in stored_name
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283193+00:00 app[web.1]:     hashed_name = self.stored_name(clean_name)
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283194+00:00 app[web.1]:     cache_name = self.clean_name(self.hashed_name(name))
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283195+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 94, in hashed_name
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283196+00:00 app[web.1]:     (clean_name, self))
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283197+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: The file 'css/style.css' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7ff8f01577d0>.
2016-10-25T18:49:16.283192+00:00 app[web.1]:     return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
```

And this is my static settings :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Here's my template, base-html:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            {% block title %}
                My Hello Web App Project
            {% endblock %}
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
             href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
        {% block header %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Hello Web App</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'browse' %}">Browse</a>
                    </li>
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'auth_logout' %}">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">Register</a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>  
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the file `css/style.css` exist, and if so, what is the full pathname?  Also what is your static path setting?

Comment: Yes, it does. collection/static/css/style.css I added my static path setting at the bottom.

Comment: `collection/static/css/style.css` doesn't seem to match the `STATIC_URL` setting of `/static/`.  (But since you didn't tell us the absolute file path, it's hard to tell.)

Comment: Also, can you show us the template that contains the css file reference?

Comment: I added my template above. The full pathname of the css file is https://[myapp_name].herokuapp.com/static/css/style.css

Comment: Tried to follow what's written in the whitenoise document, fixed a few things in settings but it's still showing me an error

Comment: Ok, I commented out this part : STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage' and now it's showing the app! But I still see "the css is not found" in heroku logs.;

Comment: What happens when you run `python manage.py collectstatic` locally?

Comment: I was asking for the _filesystem path_ to the css file, not the web url.  Also, what is `BASE_DIR` in your settings?

Comment: @D.Evans It works fine I think. It just asks me to overwrite existing staticfiles.

Comment: Oh, I 'm sorry! css file path : /myhellowebapp/collection/static/css/style.css

Comment: @JohnGordon  BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))